# How I can fix "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python

I'm working on a kata in codewars called Fat Fingers, here are the instructions:

> Freddy has a really fat left pinky finger, and every time Freddy tries
> to type an A, he accidentally hits the CapsLock key! Given a string
> that Freddy wants to type, emulate the keyboard misses where each A
> supposedly pressed is replaced with CapsLock, and return the string
> that Freddy actually types. It doesn't matter if the A in the string
> is capitalized or not. When CapsLock is enabled, capitalization is
> reversed, but punctuation is not affected.

And here are the examples:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
-> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lZY DOG."

"The end of the institution, maintenance, and administration of government, is to secure the existence of the body politic, to protect it, and to furnish the individuals who compose it with the power of enjoying in safety and tranquillity their natural rights, and the blessings of life: and whenever these great objects are not obtained, the people have a right to alter the government, and to take measures necessary for their safety, prosperity and happiness."
-> "The end of the institution, mINTENnce, ND dministrTION OF GOVERNMENT, IS TO SECURE THE EXISTENCE OF THE BODY POLITIC, TO PROTECT IT, nd to furnish the individuLS WHO COMPOSE IT WITH THE POWER OF ENJOYING IN Sfety ND TRnquillity their nTURl rights, ND THE BLESSINGS OF LIFE: nd whenever these greT OBJECTS re not obtINED, THE PEOPLE Hve  RIGHT TO lter the government, ND TO Tke meSURES NECESSry for their sFETY, PROSPERITY nd hPPINESS."

"aAaaaaAaaaAAaAa"
-> ""

My code:

```
def fat_fingers(string):
   #create a variable called capitalized ans initial it to false
    #iterate a string and check if the current letter equal to A
    #if its equal to a i will reverse the capitalize var.
    #when i will append the c letter i will check if the capitalized = true
    #then i will append it to a string Uppercased else i will do it Undercased
    caps=False
    stri=""
    string2= list(string)
    for i in string2:
        letter = string2[i]
        if letter == "a" or letter == "A" :
            caps = not caps
        else:
            if caps :
                stri += letter.upper()
            else:
                stri+=letter
        return str(stri)
```

Comment: Hello, it happens when you subset a list with string. As you are iterating throught string i is not a int but character. So in your case letter should be equal to i not string[2] = i  ..

Comment: What do you think `for i in string2:`, `letter = string2[i]` do? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements.

Comment: for i in string2: letter = i

Answer (score 1):

The for loop `for i in string2:` iterates over the letters of `string2`.
You instead are expecting it to give you indices over the string.

Just use `i` as the letter:

```py
def fat_fingers(string):
   #create a variable called capitalized ans initial it to false
    #iterate a string and check if the current letter equal to A
    #if its equal to a i will reverse the capitalize var.
    #when i will append the c letter i will check if the capitalized = true
    #then i will append it to a string Uppercased else i will do it Undercased
    caps=False
    stri=""
    string2= list(string)
    for letter in string2:
        if letter == "a" or letter == "A" :
            caps = not caps
        else:
            if caps :
                stri += letter.upper()
            else:
                stri+=letter
        return str(stri)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fat_fingers(string):
    
    caps=False
    stri=""
    string2= list(string)
    
    for i in string2:
        print (i)
        # This line was incorrect
        letter = i
        if letter == "a" or letter == "A" :
            caps = not caps
        else:
            if caps :
                stri += letter.upper()
            else:
                stri+=letter
        return str(stri)
```